# Make a copy of parent-child structure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, recursive-query

I have a table `MODELS` to which several `ITEMS` can belong. The `ITEMS` table is a hierarchical table with a self join on the `PARENT` column. Root level items will have `Null` in `PARENT`. Items can go to any level deep.

```
create table MODELS (
   MODELID              int                  identity,
   MODELNAME            nvarchar(200)         not null,
   constraint PK_MODELS primary key (MODELID)
)
go

create table ITEMS (
   ITEMID               int                  identity,
   MODELID              int                  not null,
   PARENT               int                  null,
   ITEMNUM              nvarchar(20)         not null,
   constraint PK_ITEMS primary key (ITEMID)
)
go

alter table ITEMS
   add constraint FK_ITEMS_MODEL foreign key (MODELID)
      references MODELS (MODELID)
go

alter table ITEMS
   add constraint FK_ITEMS_ITEMS foreign key (PARENT)
      references ITEMS (ITEMID)
go
```

I wish to create stored procedure to copy a row in the `MODELS` table into a new row and also copy the entire structure in `ITEMS` as well.

For example, if I have the following in `ITEMS`:

```
ITEMID    MODELID    PARENT    ITEMNUM
  1          1        Null       A
  2          1        Null       B
  3          1        Null       C
  4          1          1        A.A
  5          1          2        B.B
  6          1          4        A.A.A
  7          1          4        A.A.B
  8          1          3        C.A
  9          1          3        C.B
 10          1          9        C.B.A
```

I'd like to create new Model row and copies of the 10 Items that should be as follows:

```
ITEMID    MODELID    PARENT    ITEMNUM
  11          2       Null       A
  12          2       Null       B
  13          2       Null       C
  14          2        11        A.A
  15          2        12        B.B
  16          2        14        A.A.A
  17          2        14        A.A.B
  18          2        13        C.A
  19          2        13        C.B
  20          2        19        C.B.A
```

I will pass the `MODELID` to be copied as a parameter to the Stored Procedure. The tricky part is setting the `PARENT` column correctly. I think this will need to be done recursively.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why aren't you using [hierarchyid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx)?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, this is a SQL Server 2008 database

Comment: Doesn't matter, `hierarchyid` was added in 2005

Comment: Interesting. I will check it out

Answer (score 8):

The solution described here will work correctly in multi-user environment. You don't need to lock the whole table. You don't need to disable self-referencing foreign key. You don't need recursion.

(ab)use [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) with `OUTPUT` clause.

`MERGE` can `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` rows. In our case we need only to `INSERT`. 1=0 is always false, so the `NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` part is always executed. In general, there could be other branches, see docs. `WHEN MATCHED` is usually used to `UPDATE`; `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` is usually used to `DELETE`, but we don't need them here.

This convoluted form of `MERGE` is equivalent to simple `INSERT`, but unlike simple `INSERT` its `OUTPUT` clause allows to refer to the columns that we need. It allows to retrieve columns from both source and destination tables thus saving a mapping between old and new IDs.

**sample data**

```
DECLARE @Items TABLE (
   ITEMID               int                  identity,
   MODELID              int                  not null,
   PARENT               int                  null,
   ITEMNUM              nvarchar(20)         not null
)

INSERT INTO @Items (MODELID, PARENT, ITEMNUM) VALUES
(1, Null, 'A'),
(1, Null, 'B'),
(1, Null, 'C'),
(1,   1 , 'A.A'),
(1,   2 , 'B.B'),
(1,   4 , 'A.A.A'),
(1,   4 , 'A.A.B'),
(1,   3 , 'C.A'),
(1,   3 , 'C.B'),
(1,   9 , 'C.B.A');
```

I omit the code that duplicates the `Model` row. Eventually you'll have ID of original Model and new Model.

```
DECLARE @SrcModelID int = 1;
DECLARE @DstModelID int = 2;
```

Declare a table variable (or temp table) to hold the mapping between old and new item IDs.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(OldItemID int, NewItemID int);
```

Make a copy of `Items` remembering the mapping of IDs in the table variable and keeping old `PARENT` values.

```
MERGE INTO @Items
USING
(
    SELECT ITEMID, PARENT, ITEMNUM
    FROM @Items AS I
    WHERE MODELID = @SrcModelID
) AS Src
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (MODELID, PARENT, ITEMNUM)
VALUES
    (@DstModelID
    ,Src.PARENT
    ,Src.ITEMNUM)
OUTPUT Src.ITEMID AS OldItemID, inserted.ITEMID AS NewItemID
INTO @T(OldItemID, NewItemID)
;
```

Update old `PARENT` values with new IDs

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT I.ITEMID, I.PARENT, T.NewItemID
    FROM
        @Items AS I
        INNER JOIN @T AS T ON T.OldItemID = I.PARENT
    WHERE I.MODELID = @DstModelID
)
UPDATE CTE
SET PARENT = NewItemID
;
```

Check the results

```
SELECT * FROM @Items;
```

Comment: This looks promising. I will try it out tomorrow and let you know... I have about 500+ items for a model.

Comment: `OUTPUT Src.ITEMID AS OldItemID, inserted.ITEMID AS NewItemID` to get both the old and new ID's - that trick just saved my day.  +1 and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without recursion. But you need to lock the table first maybe to be sure that it works fine.

```
insert into items (Modelid, Parent, ITEMNUM)
 select  2 as modelId, 
          MAP.currId as Parent,
          MO.ITEMNUM  
  from (
        ( select * from items where MODELID = 1) MO
  left join 
        ( select IDENT_CURRENT('ITEMS') + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY itemid ) currID , 
                 i.ItemID 
          from ITEMS i
         where modelid = 1 ) MAP
  on MO.Parent= MAP.ItemID 
   )  ORDER BY MO.ItemID
```

The idea behind it is that we select all rows from original model in ITEM table and we generate fake ID for them.

The fake ID is :

```
Row 1 = current identity + 1,
Row 2 = current identity + 2, 
etc.
```

After that we have mapping : oldid -> newid

Then we insert original model to ITEM table like it is but we replace Parent by record from our mapping.

The issue that I can see is that some ItemID may still not exist for Parent when we insert rows (ie. we insert row that will have ItemID 20 but its Parent is 21). For that we may need to disable constraint on Parent for the time of execution of this insert. After that we supposed to enable it again. Data will be correct of course.

Comment: I added explanation to my answer. It's a little bit tricky but very efficient.

Comment: @dcieslak, you need to specify `ORDER BY` if you want to guarantee the order in which new `IDENTITY` values are generated during `INSERT`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov  Order by will not help. Check the last  few sentences. There is a solution for that what you mentioned.

Comment: @dcieslak, right now the problem with the query is that you generate new fake IDs (`currID`) using `ROW_NUMBER` in a specific order (`ORDER BY itemid`). But actual `IDENTITY` values that will be generated in the `Items` table by the `INSERT` can be generated in any order, unless you specify `ORDER BY`.